# Urls.py says my view is not defined (class based view)

Tags: django, django-urls, django-class-based-views

This is my urls.py for my project:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^CMS/', include('CMSApp.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

and this is my urls.py for my app (CMSApp):

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns(
        'CMSApp.views',
        url(r'^users$', user_list.as_view()),
        url(r'^users/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', user_detail.as_view()),
)
```

When I go to

```
CMS/users
```

it gives me a name error saying that

```
name 'user_list' is not defined
```

Any idea why?

When I do

```
from CMSApp import views

urlpatterns = patterns(
        '',
        url(r'^users$', views.user_list.as_view()),
)
```

it works but I'm just wondering why the former does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you're using Django 1.8 for your project; the behavior you're trying to use was removed in 1.8, as documented here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/#django-conf-urls-patterns

Comment: That's referring to referencing views as strings, which OP isn't doing. They have simply failed to import the module.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I think JoeyWihelm has the right answer. I knew that doing "from CMSApp import views" would work (I mentioned it in my question). I was just wondering why the former does not work (having 'CMSApp.views' in my urlpatterns). I'm wondering this because even without doing "from CMSApp import views", if I put "'CMSApp.views', url(r'^users$', 'user_list', name='user_list')" it used to work (but now when I'm using class based views, it stopped working for some reason). This is because, as Joey / the django 1.8 documentation explained, there is a more recommended way of doing it now.

Comment: Technically, Daniel Roseman is correct, you were receiving that error because you were missing an import. I had overlooked that part, simply noticing use of the old style urlpatterns.

Answer (score 1):

You have to import

```
from CMSApp.views import user_list
```

Otherwise django won't know `user_list` is defined.

If you just use `user_list` without importing it explictly, python will consider it is a local variable and return `NameError`. 
Once `user_list` is defined in views.py, you have to explicitly tell python to search for it there.